# Corona vs Xamarin? what should I pick up?

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, coronasdk

I have to develop an game application using either Xamarin or Corona Framework, I have search a lot information and found out that both offer a bunch of nice tools to create apps, I have only developed games using Java with the sdk for Android but it turns pretty hard to handle the physic manually because you spend a lot of time trying to get specific behaviors so that is why I need to use Xamarin or Corona and also because I need to get builds for Android and IOS, I have read that if you want to get a APP for IOS you can not do it with Corona instead you have to do it some other way like sending your code to a third party to finally get your APP I don't have a MAC only PC, so is better for me to have it all in a single machine, It is a 2D game so not a big deal but what software would be better to get the both the APP and APK? and does it have the hdpi,ldpo,mdpi,xhdpi,xxhdpi like in Eclipse SDK to scale the Views, Text and stuff like that?

Answer (score 2):

Use Corona, try to fit your requeriments in what Corona can do, yo can develop in pc, check if work on Android,while you are developing and when you finish check if work on ios, you can use services like www.macincloud.com or hackintosh if you have licence ;)

Xamarin is more powerfull , but needs more knowledge and a mac ir very recommended, if you want to go that way i recommend you check Monogame and cocos2dxna, but for you is not recommended.